# T character after .css extension(style.css?T) and numbers after linked images (image.jpg?1301930793)

Tags: html, drupal

Please, could anyone tell me what does above mentioned mean?

I'm optimizing one Drupal website for better search engine results and I have, for me, strange source code.

I'm PHP coder and I perfectly know rules of engagement of making dynamic URL's, but meaning of dynamic URL on something that should be perfectly static HTML (/sites/all/modules/cck/theme/content-module.css?T) and (img src="http://domainname/sites/default/files/slide1.jpg?1301930728") is totally unknown to me.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possiblethat they aren't as dynamic as you think.

they may be rewritten urls to mimic static webpages, but are actually php script.

Also, it could also be a technique to make sure the client doesn't cache the files.